# Wordpress, redirect, permalinks

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks

I changed the permalinks from **%post_name%** to **/%author%/%post_name%/**
Now the old website addresses don't work.
How do I redirect old **%postname%** addresses to **/%author%/%postname%/** ?

Now I want use **/%author%/%postname%/** but old adrress must works too.

I searched for a solution using Google search, but I didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect the old URLs with the %postname% permalink structure to the new URLs with the /%author%/%postname%/ permalink structure, you can use a plugin such as **Redirection** or **Simple 301 Redirects**